# Join only when relation data exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select

These are my tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories (
  category_id serial primary key,
  category text not null,
  user_id int not null
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS activities (
  activity_id serial primary key,
  activity text not null,
  user_id int not null
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories_to_activities (
  category_id int not null REFERENCES categories (category_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  activity_id int not null REFERENCES activities (activity_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT category_activity_pkey PRIMARY KEY (category_id, activity_id)
);
```

This is the query I'm using to get all activities with their categories.

```
SELECT a.*, ARRAY_AGG ( ROW_TO_JSON (c) ) categories
FROM activities a
JOIN categories_to_activities ca ON a.activity_id = ca.activity_id
JOIN categories c ON ca.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE a.user_id = ${userId}
GROUP BY a.activity_id
```

The issue is that if an activity does not have a category assigned, it won't get returned.

I'm having trouble combining `JOIN` with `CASE`, which I suppose is what I need. Essentially I want  to `JOIN` only when there is some record in `categories_to_activities`?

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `left join`, and return `null`s for activities without categories:

```sql
SELECT    a.*, 
          CASE WHEN ca.activity_id IS NOT NULL THEN ARRAY_AGG(ROW_TO_JSON(c)) 
                                               ELSE ARRAY[]::JSON[] 
          END as categories
FROM      activities a
LEFT JOIN categories_to_activities ca ON a.activity_id = ca.activity_id
LEFT JOIN categories c ON ca.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE     a.user_id = ${userId}
GROUP BY  a.activity_id
```

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` due to, I guess, `ROW_TO_JSON` not being able to find the category. I need that CASE here in SELECT now, no?

Comment: @VidličkaLujVitóón That doesn't look like a PostgeSQL error. Are you running this query out of Node.js? If so, I'd check it there, not in the query itself, but the using `case` would also do the trick

Comment: Oh yeah, it was an error thrown by JS later. Care to update your answer with that CASE? I'd like to get empty array instead of [null]. Thanks!

Comment: @VidličkaLujVitóón actually, using `coalesce` would be even cleaner than `case` - see my edited answer

Comment: Neat! Almost there. Seems like a typo somewhere. `syntax error at or near "categories"`.

Comment: Still seeing it as [null], with your updated answer. Geez I need lots of hand holding haha.

Comment: Ended up using
`
CASE WHEN ca.activity_id IS NOT NULL
  THEN ARRAY_AGG ( ROW_TO_JSON (c) )
  ELSE ARRAY[]::JSON[]
END as categories`

Comment: @VidličkaLujVitóón Good catch! I missed how `array_agg` handles `null`s. I've edited this into my answer so it will be more useful for someone looking it up in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up with, thanks to @Murenik

```
SELECT    a.*,
          CASE WHEN ca.activity_id IS NOT NULL
            THEN ARRAY_AGG ( ROW_TO_JSON (c) )
            ELSE ARRAY[]::JSON[]
          END as categories
FROM      activities a
LEFT JOIN categories_to_activities ca ON a.activity_id = ca.activity_id
LEFT JOIN categories c ON ca.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE     a.user_id = ${userId}
GROUP BY  a.activity_id, ca.activity_id
```